# How to handle multi callout in test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, apex-webservice, webservicemock

I have webservice class which have multi callout.For the first callout i have some list of URl's.From the list of URL's I want to do the second callout and so on.
 apexCode:

```
global with sharing class Sample_C2GUpdateVersionPrice {
    static Double dbPriceHT;
    static Double dbTVNAmount;
    webservice static String VersionPrice(String oppCarid) {
        Sample_DZC2GVersionPriceDetails_CLS versionPrice=new Sample_DZC2GVersionPriceDetails_CLS(oppCarid);
        List<double> lstPriceValues =versionPrice.getVersionPrice();
        if (lstPriceValues!=null && lstPriceValues.size()>0) {
            dbPriceHT     = lstPriceValues.get(0);
            dbTVNAmount   = lstPriceValues.get(1);  
        }
        Opportunity_car_set__c oppCarset = [SELECT Price_HT__c FROM Opportunity_car_set__c where id=:oppCarid];
        oppCarset .Price_HT__c=dbPriceHT;
        oppCarset .Sample_TVN_Amount__c=dbTVNAmount;
        update oppCarset ;
        return ('/' + oppCarset.id);
    } 

}
Weservice class:

public class Sample_DZC2GVersionPriceDetails_CLS {
    public String strJSON {get;set;}
    public String strGeturl {get;set;}
    public String strGetcountrycode {get;set;}
    public String strGetCurrency {get;set;}
    public String strModelCode {get;set;}
    public String strVersionCode {get;set;}
    public String strVersionDocUrl {get;set;}
    public String strPriceListURL {get;set;}
    public String strOppid {get;set;}
    public double strversionPrice{get;set;}
    public double strversionPriceTVN{get;set;}
    public List<String> lstModelcalOut = new List<String>(); //to get list of model code
    public List<String> lstDoCcalOut = new List<String>(); //to get list of docurls
    public Map<String,String> mVersion     = new map<String,String>();  //Contains model code+doc url
    public List<double> lstVersionPrices = new List<double>();
    Sample_JSON2ApexC2G_CLS obj = null;
    public string strModel{get;set;}
    public string strVersion{get;set;} 
    public string strid{get;set;} 
    public Sample_JSON2C2GMainURL_CLS objUrl = null;
    public Sample_JSONC2GDocURL_CLS docObj=null;

    public Sample_DZC2GVersionPriceDetails_CLS(string strOppid,String strModelName, String strVersionName) {

        Sample_CountryInfo__c cs = Sample_CountryInfo__c.getInstance('Algeria');
        strGeturl         =    cs.Sample_C2GURL__c;
        strGetcountrycode =    cs.Sample_CountryCode__c;
        strGetCurrency    =    cs.Sample_Currency__c;
        strModel=strModelName;
        strVersion=strVersionName;
        strid=strOppid;
        Opportunity_car_set__c opp=[SELECT Model__r.ProductCode,Version__r.Sample_C2G_version_code__c FROM Opportunity_car_set__c where Model__r.name =: strModel and Version__r.name =: strVersion and id=:strid];    
        strModelCode    = opp.Model__r.ProductCode;
        strVersionCode  = opp.Version__r.Sample_C2G_version_code__c;
        strOppid        = opp.id;
        system.debug('<<strOppid'+ strOppid);

    }
    public Sample_DZC2GVersionPriceDetails_CLS(string strOppid) {

        Sample_CountryInfo__c cs = Sample_CountryInfo__c.getInstance('Algeria');
        strGeturl         =    cs.Sample_C2GURL__c;
        strGetcountrycode =    cs.Sample_CountryCode__c;
        strGetCurrency    =    cs.Sample_Currency__c;
        Opportunity_car_set__c opp=[SELECT Model__r.ProductCode,Version__r.Sample_C2G_version_code__c FROM Opportunity_car_set__c where id=:strOppid];    
        strModelCode    = opp.Model__r.ProductCode;
        strVersionCode  = opp.Version__r.Sample_C2G_version_code__c;
        strOppid        = opp.id;
        system.debug('strOppid<<<<<<<'+ strOppid);

    }

    //Common method to Parse the JSON
    public String init(String strVersionURL) {

        try {
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();
            httpReq.setEndpoint(strVersionURL);
            httpReq.setHeader('Accept','application/JSON');
            httpReq.setMethod('GET');
            HttpResponse response = http.send(httpReq);
            strJSON= response.getBody();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            system.debug('<<Method: init Exception ::'+ ex);
        } 
        return  strJSON;     
    }

    //Used for Getting ModelCode and Doc URL in Map
    public Map<String, String> getJSONFromREST() {

        strJSON = init(strGeturl); 
        objUrl = Sample_JSON2C2GMainURL_CLS.parse(strJSON);
        List<Sample_JSON2C2GMainURL_CLS.Docs> lstDocs;
        lstDocs=objUrl .Docs; 
        for(Sample_JSON2C2GMainURL_CLS.Docs strDocs:lstDocs){
            string strModelIdCode=strDocs.docId.modelSpecCode;
            lstModelcalOut.add(strModelIdCode);
            string strDocUrl=strDocs.doc;
            lstDoCcalOut .add(strDocUrl);
        }
        for(integer i=0;i<lstModelcalOut.size();i++) {
            mVersion.put(lstModelcalOut.get(i),lstDoCcalOut.get(i));
        }
        system.debug('mVersion===>'+mVersion);
        return mVersion;       
    }

    //Used to get Version Price URL
    public String getVersionPriceURL() {

        Map<string,String> mVersionVal=getJSONFromREST();
        if(mVersionVal.containsKey(strModelCode)) {
            strVersionDocUrl= mVersionVal.get(strModelCode);
        }
        strJSON = init(strVersionDocUrl); 
        docObj= Sample_JSONC2GDocURL_CLS.parse(strJSON);
        system.debug('docObj<<<<<<<'+ docObj);

        strPriceListURL=docObj.PricesData.pricesList;
        return strPriceListURL;         
    }


    public List<double> getVersionPrice() {

           String strVersionPriceURL=getVersionPriceURL();
           String strJSON = init(strVersionPriceURL);
           obj = Sample_JSON2ApexC2G_CLS.parse(strJSON);
           /*some code------------

           */
            lstVersionPrices.add(strversionPriceTVN);
            return lstVersionPrices;

    } 

}

    Test class:

@isTest
public with sharing class Sample_C2GUpdateVersionPrice_Test {
    static TestMethod void versionPriceTest() {
    Sample_CountryInfo__c cs = new Sample_CountryInfo__c(Name = 'Algeria' , Sample_C2GURL__c = 'http://dz.co.rplug.renault.com/range',Sample_CountryCode__c = 'DZ' , Sample_Currency__c = 'DZD');
    insert cs;

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.name = 'test1';
        opp.stagename = 'Draft';
        opp.closedate = System.Today();
        insert opp;
        Product2 pModel=new Product2();
        pModel.Brand__c='Renault';
        pModel.Name='DZ-Captur';
        pModel.Country_code__c='DZ';
        pModel.Parent_Product__c=null;
        pModel.IsActive = true;
        pModel.Market__c='Test';
        insert pModel;
        Product2 pVersion=new Product2();
        pVersion.Name='DZ-Captur';
        pVersion.Parent_Product__c=pModel.id;
        pVersion.IsActive = true;
        insert pVersion;
        Opportunity_car_set__c oppCarSet = new Opportunity_car_set__c();
        oppCarSet.name = 'uma';
        oppCarSet.Brand__c=pModel.Brand__c;
        oppCarSet.Model__c=pModel.id;
        oppCarSet.Version__c=pVersion.id;
        oppCarSet.opportunity__c = opp.id;
        oppCarSet.Quantity__c = 2;
        oppCarSet.Price_HT__c =420.0;
        oppCarSet.Sample_TVN_Amount__c=89.7;
        insert oppCarSet;

        Test.Starttest();
        Sample_DZC2GVersionPriceDetails_CLS versionPrice1=new Sample_DZC2GVersionPriceDetails_CLS(oppCarSet.id);

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Sample_C2GMain_MockHttpResponseGenerator ());    
        Map<String, String> mapVal=new  Map<String, String>();
        mapVal=versionPrice1.getJSONFromREST();
        system.debug('lstcalOut>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'+mapVal);
        string strURL=mapVal.get('SFN');
        versionPrice1.init(strURL);
        String strDoc=versionPrice1.getVersionPriceURL();


        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Sample_C2GDoc_MockHttpResponseGenerator ());



        List<double> tstList = versionPrice1.getVersionPrice ();
        Sample_C2GUpdateVersionPrice.VersionPrice(cs.Sample_C2GURL__c);
        Test.StopTest();


    }
}

    Mock class:



 @isTest
    global class Rfleet_C2GDoc_MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
        // Implement this interface method
        global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
           System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.setBody('{\"requestedURI\":\"http://dz.co.rplug.re.com/doc/baa\",\"URI\":\"http://dz.co.rplug.ras.com/doc/baa\",\"canonicalURI\":\"http://dz.co.rplug.ras.com/doc/baa#this\",\"configuration\":\"http://dz.co.rplug.ras.com/c/baa/A\",\"docId\":{\"program\":\"X43\",\"phase\":\"2\",\"modelSpecCode\":\"SFN\",\"modelKind\":\"TR\",\"market\":\"ALGERI\",\"tariffNumber\":\"9347\",\"tariffAdditiveNumber\":\"00\",\"commercialKind\":\"VP\",\"creationTimeStamp\":\"1444119901628\",\"brand\":\"APL03\",\"clientId\":\"TARIF\",\"clientType\":\"GP\",\"localSemiclair\":\"SFN\"},\"validity\":{\"applicationDate\":\"2015-10-07\",\"expirationDate\":null},\"diversityData\":{\"localSemiClair\":\"http://dz.co.rplug.ras.com/localsemiclair/baa\",\"specificationCategories\":\"http://dz.co.rplug.ras.com/speccats/baa\",\"versionsCategories\":\"http://dz.co.rplug.ras.com/category/baa\"},\"presentationData\":{\"marketingModelPresentation\":\"http://dz.co.rplug.ras.com/pres/baa\"},\"pricesData\":{\"priceType\":[{\"reference\":\"PVCHT\",\"currency\":\"DZD\"},{\"reference\":\"TAUX1\",\"currency\":\"%\"},{\"reference\":\"TVAHRK\",\"currency\":\"DZD\"},{\"reference\":\"PVCDEM\",\"currency\":\"DZD\"},{\"reference\":\"PVCTTC\",\"currency\":\"DZD\"}],\"defaultPriceType\":{\"reference\":\"PVCTTC\",\"currency\":\"DZD\"},\"defaultPriceTypeVersion\":{\"reference\":\"PVCTTC\",\"currency\":\"DZD\"},\"defaultPriceTypeOption\":{\"reference\":\"PVCTTC\",\"currency\":\"DZD\"},\"pricesList\":\"http://dz.co.rplug.ras.com/pricelist/baa\"}}');
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }
```

For the getJSONfromrest i pass the url which value is coming from custom setting.this is the first callout.It will give list of URL's.From that i will take one URL and perform second callout.For each callout we have to write seperate mockclass?

Please help me out from this !!

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You answered your own question. Yes, you write a separate mock.

Comment: If i write a seperate mock class then it failed.For example in "getJSONfromrest " am performing a callout.So i have written mock class.That method is covered.then for next method "getVersionPriceURl" i have another callout.If i add another mock in test class then my covered lines in "getJSONfromrest " also uncovered.and got failed @crmprogdev

Comment: You have to do the mock callout and get the mock response of the 1st one before you can test the 2nd one.

Comment: I tried like this.but it gives error !!

Comment: Above test clas i have put two mock like that only.

Comment: I don't see any system.debugs or system.asserts to help tell you where your problems are with your code. See [How do I start to debug my own Apex code?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36582/how-do-i-start-to-debug-my-own-apex-code/36616#36616).

Comment: @crmprogdev I have tried with system.debug .the frst mock class is executed.When i add second mock class the response is null in debug

Comment: That sounds like useful information doesn't it? You're making progress on solving your own problem. What do you think that is telling you? Is there someplace in your code you can add debug statements between the two points (like in the actual code) that might help you troubleshoot why you're getting a null response?

Comment: @crmprogdev I have added all my mockclass for each callout. but now when i add this line  Sample_C2GUpdateVersionPrice.VersionPrice(oppcarst.id); i got error like "Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts" please guide me !

Comment: I'd highly recommend you go to [Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules) and work your way through the Apex Integration Services Module, perhaps beginning [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_rest_callouts).